# positioning objects on main layout fails unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bkgrndclr">

    <Button
        android="@+id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search Images"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button
        android="@id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search Web"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgbtn" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imgbtn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I set my buttons to the bottom of the view and the textbox above them but why all display linearly. The button Search Images is displayed first then the Search Web then The textbox and they are not located at the bottom, which is not what I want.

Comment: change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: But one button disappears and the textbox movex up to the top of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described what you do want... But I took a guess that you want a layout on the bottom of the screen like this:

```
|                                               |
| (EditText                                   ) |
|                            (Button)  (Button) |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bkgrndclr"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnImages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Search Images"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWeb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnImages"
        android:text="Search Web"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnImages"
        android:inputType="text"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the second button, change the id of the button to `"+@id/imgbtn1"` so it won't collide with the first.

change `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgbtn"` to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

where do you want the EditText to be?

Comment: Thank you Tamir, I would want it to be above the two buttons but should be at the bottom

Comment: oh, yeah, and change android="@+id/imgbtn" to android:id="@+id/imgbtn" (and the other ids of course) :)

Answer (score 0):

If your Views father is LinearLayout "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"" has no meaning...
You need to change the Linear to Relative
And if you want the EditText to be above the Buttons give it:

```
android:layout_above="@id/imgbtn"
```

To your buttons give DIFFERENT ID's! and change them both to alignParentBottom